# php webservice framework

Tags: php

I need to write a php based web service. I believe I have to write all the necessary code by myself. 
I do not want to reinvent the wheel if there is already some framework to write a php based web service ?

Thank you

Comment: not only that there are hundreds of examples on php... its a bad choice for webservices.

Comment: @Najzero, PHP is a *fine* choice for web services... as long as they're RESTful services instead of SOAP.

Comment: @Charles why is php not considered a gud choice for SOAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two ways :

- First, use the PHP5 soap methods https://www.php.net/manual/en//book.soap.php
- Second, use a library like nuSOAP which will allow you to generate the wsdl automatically. This library as some inconvenients like the unability to use objects to manage the service. http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/

Comment: Thanks for the help, nusoap looks promising..